# Slack API: Creating group thru groups.create doesn't reflect in conversations.list

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am working with slack API to create channels for my team thru its API.

There are some channels on the team that have been created using the web UI and some that I have created using `groups.create` method.

When I fetch the list of `channels` using `conversations.list` method, the `groups`/`channels` that I created using `groups.create` aren't fetched!! Why?

```
sc = slack_client()
res = sc.api_call("conversations.list", exclude_archived=1, types=['private_channel'])
```

And how do I fetch the channels created using `groups.create`?

Comment: do you see those groups with groups.list?

Comment: I would not regard your question as not self-sufficient. Please post at least the exact syntax you are using with `conversations.list`.

Comment: Just did. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue.

Actually the number of groups had exceeded 100 and the default length of response in `conversations.list` is 100. Just had to tweak the `limit` parameter passed in `conversations.list` to get all the channels.

Initially I was using:

```
sc = slack_client()
res = sc.api_call("conversations.list", exclude_archived=1, types=['private_channel'])
```

Now I changed it to

```
sc = slack_client()
res = sc.api_call("conversations.list", exclude_archived=1, types=['private_channel'], limit= 999)
```